# How can I change the default naming of a precompiled View in .Views.dll and use that name to call via Controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, razorengine

I am trying to make a modular architecture using ASP.Net Core 2.2 and MVC. Essentially I  have a base ASP.Net Core 2.2 web app. And then I want to keep adding class libraries to act as features to my app. I am routing to these features by configuring AreaViewLocationFormats.
My Class Libraries are targeting SDK - Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor. On Build I do see .Views.dll and my base app is able to scan these and add to the application factory.

At the app start up I am scanning dlls and Views.dll of these class libraries and then adding them to the application parts like this (I have simplified this so that I can share):

```
foreach (var file in plugInFolder.GetFileSystemInfos("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    Assembly assembly;
                    try
                    {
                        assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(file.FullName);
                    }
                    catch (FileLoadException ex)
                    {
                        // If assembly is already loaded, we'll just catch it and continue to the next one, plugins can have same dependencies:
                        if (ex.Message == "Assembly with same name is already loaded")
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        throw;
                    }


                    //If its a View Assembly then we need to load it differently:
                    if (assembly.FullName.Contains(".Views"))
                    {
                        mvcBuilder.ConfigureApplicationPartManager(mgr => {
                            foreach (var b in CompiledRazorAssemblyApplicationPartFactory.GetDefaultApplicationParts(assembly))
                            {                                
                                mvcBuilder.ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm => apm.ApplicationParts.Add(b));
                            }

                        });

                    }
                    // If plugin hasn't been loaded already
                    else if (!plugins.ContainsKey(pluginFolder.Name) &&   // plug in isn't loaded already and
                            pluginFolder.Name == assembly.GetName().Name) // plug in Name matches Folder Name {Our convention}
                    {
                        plugins.Add(pluginFolder.Name, new PlugInInfo { Name = pluginFolder.Name, Assembly = assembly, Path = pluginFolder.PhysicalPath });
                        //plugin load:
                        mvcBuilder.AddApplicationPart(assembly);


                    }


                }
```

The issue is with the Views.dll in that they have below weird attributes(checked via ILSpy) :

```
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue)]
[assembly: RazorCompiledItem(typeof(Views_Home_Index), "mvc.1.0.view", "/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")]
[assembly: RazorView("/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", typeof(Views_Home_Index))]
```

I think that because of the "/Views/Home/Index.cshtml" in above compilation I can only call my views if I use

```
return View("/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")
```

The issue with that is - I can't use the same Views-Home-Index naming with other class libraries.
For now, I can work around without precompiling views and using cshtml files. But I wanted to have the advantage of pre-compiled views.
I have referred to MS docs for Razor SDK but failed to get appropriate help or may be I missed something.
Is there anything I can do to fix these names of the compiled Views? Please guide.

I believe that naming is coming from the location of the View per MVC convention but I want to be able to call my view by

```
return View("<FeatureName>/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

But currently it only works with:

```
return  View("Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to aspnet core team and I have an answer. Please refer following if you are also stuck here and upvote my question :)
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7112